# Cannot echo correctly in PHP

Tags: php, echo

So whenever I try to make a basic PHP page, it doesn't work. The echo is glitching out, instead of outputting the text I put in, it outputs the text, then anything after it.

So if I were to put

```
<?php

echo "<p>Hello World!</>";

?>
```

It would output `Hello World!"; ?>`

Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="create.php" method="post">

<table border="0">

<tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="title" size="30" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Script</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" name="script" size="100" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here's my entire PHP file.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Creating Script</title>
</head>

<body>

  <?php
    echo "<p>Hello World!</>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note: Ending tag to `<p>` is `</p>`  and not `</>`

Comment: Hey - what's the name of the file? (eg index.php, for example). Has your web server been setup to handle PHP files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

If you correctly close your HTML tags things will work more reliably

EG

```
echo "<p>Hello World!</>";
```

should be

```
echo "<p>Hello World!</p>";
                       ^
```